# $S$ is an elliptic surface if and only if $\chi_\text{top}(S)=12$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let $\pi:S\to \Bbb{P}^1$ be a minimal elliptic fibration. I'm trying to understand why the following is true:

> S is rational if and only $\chi_\text{top}(S)=12$.

In Schütt and Shioda's [*Elliptic Surfaces*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1543085637) page 46 there is an indication for $(\Rightarrow)$: by minimality, $K_S^2=0$ and by Noether's formula $\chi_\text{top}(S)=12(K_S^2+\chi(S))=12\chi(S)$, so it remais to show that $\chi(S)=1$. He uses the fact that $K_S=(\chi(S)-2)F$ for a general fibre $F$ and that $K_S$ is anti-ample and concludes directly that $\chi(S)=1$. I'm not familiar with ample divisors, but as far as I could read about it, I don't understand why that follows.

For the converse $(\Leftarrow)$, I suppose the idea is to argue that $K_S=-F$ implies $K_S$ is anti-ample, but again it's not clear to me why.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You wrote the formula for $K_S$ with the wrong sign: it should be $K_S=(\chi(S)-2) F$. 

The authors write "A rational surface has $K_S$ anti-ample". That is wrong. I think they meant to say "A rational surface has $K_S$ not effective". In that case, since $\chi(S)>0$ the only choice is $\chi(S)=1$.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti, you're right, I've corrected the sign.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti, how can I see that $K_S$ cannot be effective?

Comment: Plurigenera are birational invariants. So if $S$ is rational then $h^0(S,K_S)=h^0(\mathbf P^2, K_{\mathbf P^2}) = 0$.

Comment: For the converse, I think this works: begin as with the forward direction to *conclude* that for $S$ minimal, $\chi_{top}(S) = 12$ implies $\chi(S) = 1$. Since $h^0(\mathcal O_S) = 1$, we get $h^1(\mathcal O_S) = h^2(\mathcal O_S) = h^0(K_S) = 0$ (using Serre duality for the second equality and $-F$ not effective for the third). This computes the irregularity $q = 0$. The second plurigenus $P_2 = h^0(K_S^{\otimes 2}) = h^0(-2F) = 0$ as well, which is enough to get rationality of $S$ by Castelnuovo's Rationality Criterion.